# Getting type class instance through a parent type

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I need to provide type class instances for a bunch of case classes all derived from a single trait, but as far as I understand Scala compiler expects an instance for a specific class and doesn't go up the inheritance hierarchy. So this code:

```
trait Base

sealed trait Child extends Base

case class Concrete() extends Child

trait Printable[A] {
  def print(value: A): String
}

object WtfTrait {
  def print[A](x: A)(implicit ev: Printable[A]) = {
    println(ev.print(x))
  }

  implicit val printableBase = new Printable[Base] {
    override def print(value: Base): String = value.toString
  }

  val x = Concrete()
  print(x)
}
```

doesn't compile with an error reading `could not find implicit value for parameter ev: Printable[Impl]`. Is there a way to define a single type class instance for the base trait and avoid repitition maybe by using Shapeless or something.

Comment: `Impl` is not described in your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guess you mean `Printable[Concrete]` (that's to say a `Show` typeclass instance).

Need to update to `printableBase` definition as bellow:

```
trait Base

sealed trait Child extends Base

case class Concrete() extends Child

trait Printable[A] {
  def print(value: A): String
}

object WtfTrait {
  def print[A](x: A)(implicit ev: Printable[A]) = {
    println(ev.print(x))
  }

  // HERE
  implicit def printableBase[T <: Base] = new Printable[T] {
    override def print(value: T): String = value.toString
  }

  val x = Concrete()
  print(x)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Printable` can be made contravariant by adding a `-` sign:

```
trait Printable[-A]
```

This makes `Printable[X]` a subtype of `Printable[Y]` if `Y` is a subtype of `X`. In particular, `Printable[Base]` is a subtype of `Printable[Concrete]` and can be used when the compiler looks for an implicit of that type.

Comment: Contravariance for typeclass can [hardly be recommended in scala](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scala-language/ZE83TvSWpT4/YiwJJLZRmlcJ)